# How can I fit THREE.js view to canvas size?

Tags: typescript, three.js, 3d

I would like to drag and drop element to the mouse position.
For this I need to "sync" THREE.js space to the canvas size (`{0,0}` coordinates are at the middle of the screen).
so let's say my element has a width of 500px if I drop an element with a mouse coordinates `x = 500` then object x coordinates should be `x = 250`.
At this point I am using `PerspectiveCamera`.

I relied on the explanation of [this tutorial](https://observablehq.com/@grantcuster/understanding-scale-and-the-three-js-perspective-camera) and made calculation in order to have the fov(field of view) boundaries intersect the boundaries of the green line (in the example circle height, in my case canvas width)

here is what I've done so far to calculate fov base on z position of the camera (mainly using Pythagore).

```
  calculateFOV(z:number){
    const b = z;
    const a = this.width / 2;
    const c = Math.sqrt((a**2) + (b**2));
    const cosa =  a / c;
    let angle = (Math.acos(cosa) * (180 / Math.PI));
    let resAngle = 180 - 90 - angle
    return (resAngle * 2);
  }

...

const zPosition = 40;
const fov = this.calculateFOV(zPosition);
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, this.width / this.height, 10,  zPosition);
```

but it's not working as expected.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to make it work by doing as so:

```
  calculateFOV(z:number){
    const b = z;
    //scaling mid base of fov triangle to aspect ratio
    const a = ((this.width / 2 ) / (this.width / this.height));
    //pythagore
    const c = Math.sqrt((a**2) + (b**2));
    //cosine of angle
    const cosa = a / c;
    //invert cosine to degrees
    const angle = Math.acos(cosa) * (180 / Math.PI);
    //angle left multiplied by 2
    let resAngle = (90 - angle) * 2
    return (resAngle);
  }
```

and `z = this.width`

can't really understand it but it worked by scaling mid base to the aspect ratio.

Comment: You are welcome..  I can't follow your work, but am glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your model (line?) has width W and height H.
Assume the camera is at Z.
The canvas has width w and height h.
THREE.js fov is based on height.

You need to compare the aspect ratio of the model vs. the canvas.

```
if ((W/H) < (w/h)) then fov = 2*atan2(H/2, Z);
else                    fov = 2*atan2(W*h/w/2, Z);
```

(Yes, THREE.js camera fov needs degrees)

(This gives me some confidence in my work:)

```
If the canvas aspect ratio is 4/3, H=30, W<40, Z=100, then  
  (W/H)<(4/3) and fov = 2*atan2(30/2, 100);  
If the canvas aspect ratio is 4/3, W=40, H<30, Z=100, then  
  (W/H)>(4/3) and fov = 2*atan2(40*3/4/2, 100);
```

Comment: First thank you for your anwser, I've tried it and it didn't worked, I managed to make it work and I'm going to answer my own question. Still in my answer I don't really understood what I've done so maybe you could explain it to me if you understand on your side.